# Excel VBA - Copy data from sheet with Column values as Subheaders

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA, I'm wondering if I can copy data from one sheet to another and input subheaders based off of column values.

Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve; I want to paste the columns in the same ordering from my "Data" sheet to my "Result" sheet, but in doing so, using the "CONCAT" column values as subheaders.

**Before: (Data Sheet)** [image]

**After: (Result Sheet)**
[image]

So far I have been able to copy and paste the "Data" sheet data into the "Result" sheet, in the same order and format, but I am unsure how to use the "CONCAT" column as subheaders in the code. I hope my question makes sense.

```
Sub Copy()

Sheets("Result").Cells.Clear
Sheets("Data").Columns(3).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Result").Columns(1)
Sheets("Data").Columns(4).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Result").Columns(2)
Sheets("Data").Columns(5).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Result").Columns(3)
Sheets("Data").Columns(6).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Result").Columns(4)
Sheets("Data").Columns(7).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Result").Columns(5)
Sheets("Data").Columns(8).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Result").Columns(6)
Sheets("Data").Columns(9).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Result").Columns(7)
Sheets("Data").Columns(11).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Result").Columns(8)
Sheets("Data").Columns(12).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Result").Columns(9)
Sheets("Data").Columns(13).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Result").Columns(10)
Sheets("Data").Columns(15).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Result").Columns(11)

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of copying the data 1 column at a time loop through each row. Start your loop with a comparison variable set to an empty string e.g.
prev = ""
Then for each row compare the content of the `concat` column to prev. E.g.
`If row.Cells(1,12) <> prev then

     newRow.Cells(1,2) .Value = row.Cells(1,12).Value

else

    newRow.Value = row.Value

End If`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Transform Data: Copy Given Columns and Implement 'Sub Headers'

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**The Code**

```vb
Sub TransformData()
 
    ' Define constants.
 
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const SRC_TITLE_COLUMN As Long = 17
    Dim sCopyCols(): sCopyCols = VBA.Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15)
    
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const DST_TITLE_COLUMN As String = 2
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Read the source data into an array.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
    
    Dim sData():
    With sws.UsedRange
        sData = sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL, .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge)).Value
    End With
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(sData, 1)
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = UBound(sData, 2)
    
    If scCount < SRC_TITLE_COLUMN Or scCount < Application.Max(sCopyCols) Then
        MsgBox "The data has not enough columns.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Populate a dictionary whose keys will hold the unique values
    ' from the title column, while their items will hold a collection
    ' holding each row index where the title appeared.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sr As Long, rStr As String
    
    For sr = 2 To srCount
        rStr = sData(sr, SRC_TITLE_COLUMN)
        If Len(rStr) > 0 Then
            If Not dict.Exists(rStr) Then
                Set dict(rStr) = New Collection
            End If
            dict(rStr).Add sr
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Define the destination array.
    
    Dim scUpper As Long: scUpper = UBound(sCopyCols)
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = scUpper + 1
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To srCount + dict.Count, 1 To dcCount)
    
    'Write headers.
    
    Dim sc As Long
    
    For sc = 0 To scUpper
        dData(1, sc + 1) = sData(1, sCopyCols(sc))
    Next sc
    
    ' Write data.
    
    Dim dr As Long: dr = 1 ' skip headers
    
    Dim Key, Item
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        dr = dr + 1
        dData(dr, DST_TITLE_COLUMN) = Key
        For Each Item In dict(Key)
            dr = dr + 1
            For sc = 0 To scUpper
                dData(dr, sc + 1) = sData(Item, sCopyCols(sc))
            Next sc
        Next Item
    Next Key
    
    ' Write to the destination worksheet.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
    
    Dim drg As Range:
    With dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
        Set drg = .Resize(dr, dcCount)
    End With
    
    drg.Value = dData
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Data transformed.", vbInformation

End Sub
```